# adidas script: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, nonetype

Need help with an adidas auto checkout script. Getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "adidas.py", line 169, in <module>
    checkout()
File "adidas.py", line 80, in checkout
    url = soup.find('div', {'class': 'cart_wrapper rbk_shadow_angle rbk_wrapper_checkout summary_wrapper'})['data-url']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Link to the entire script: https://github.com/kfichter/OpenATC/blob/482360a7a160136a4969d2cf0527809660d021fb/Scripts/adidas.py

Answer (score 0):

`soup.find()` is returning `None`.  You are trying to look up the key `'data-url'` in this result, but `None` does not support key lookup.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you should either change the query so it doesn't return `None`, or check that the value is not `None` before trying to access the `'data-url'` key.